# Как остановить выполнение функции в telegram bot

Tags: python, telebot

Нужно создать такую функцию, которая будет работать как подписка: подписался - присылает оповещения, отписался - не присылает. Подписаться элементарно, а отписаться у меня не получается (подписка так и шлёт сообщения, пока не вырубишь бота на сервере).
Вот один из кодов с неработающей отпиской по слову 'stop':

```
import telebot
import time

token = '...'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
print('Бот запущен!')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['sub'])
def subscribe(message):
  while message.text.lower() != '/stop':
    now = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %A %H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, now)
    time.sleep(4)

bot.polling()
```

Comment: Перекрестился. Что это такое? Зачем функция? Почему внутри хендлер? И что за хрень с бесконечным циклом? Зачем он тут? Ищите информацию по scheldule и меняйте весь код на адекватный , который есть в документации

Comment: Ту функцию-обёртку убрал, согласен не нужна. Бесконечный цикл нужен для теста, чтоб понять работает ли подписка на функцию. Цель - командой /sub подписываться, командой /stop отписываться.

Comment: Ваш способ не будет работать, он у вас запускает вечный цикл для всего бота, и он просто замрёт

Comment: Это минимальный работающий кусок моей программы. Когда запускаю целиком - присылает сообщения не только этот цикл, но и другие функции отвечают, когда я присылаю другие команды (/start, /help итд).